# text size in label

Tags: iphone, text, label

how can i limit the number of characters in a label

Comment: *How can I limit the number of characters in a label?*

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048339/label-in-my-tabel-celll  (yeah this one was first, but the other is a little clearer).

Answer (score 1):

You can truncate the text with an ellipsis automatically by setting the `frame` of the `UILabel`.

```
NSInteger newSize = 10;
label.frame = CGRectMake(label.frame.origin.x, label.frame.origin.y, label.frame.size.height,  newSize);
```

Comment: That doesn't actually limit the number of characters, it just *displays* a limited number of characters.