# label in my tabel celll

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilabel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [text size in label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047984/text-size-in-label)

thank you for your fast feedback
but that not worked for me i am using labels in table..

```
UILabel *label1 = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:1];
label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label1.text=aStation.station_name;
label1.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.76 green:0.21 blue:0.07 alpha:1.0];
[label1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Trebuchet MS" size:15]];
```

for this type of label i want to limit number of characters.
hope i will get an answer..

Comment: You control how many characters you put in the label when you assign to the text field.  You can shorten the text you put in the label if it's too many characters.  Can you describe the problem better?  What didn't work?  What did it do that is wrong?

Comment: hi lak, please post your question only one time.  If you don't get a good answer you can "edit" and add more information or clarify your question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047984/text-size-in-label

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *myString = [self getStringValue];  // Set the value any way you like.
int maxLen = 10;  // Or whatever your true maximum length is.
label.text = myString;
if (([myString length] > maxLen) label.text = [myString substringToIndex:maxLen];
```